# where does opendaylight store flow-rules? and in what format?

Tags: opendaylight

I wish to know where opendaylight controller stores flow-rules (current research show that it's in Data-store MD-SAL) is it right? and in what format this data store is? database? xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Opendaylight  Beryllium version so the data base which I can see is JSON .